How can I use Anime.js to create multiple ripples that spread outward from the center, gradually become transparent, and finally disappear?
When I create an infinite loop animation using CSS, the effect is inconsistent with the one created using Anime.js
When I create looping animations using CSS, each loop is seamless. However, when I create animations using Anime.js, there's a pause at the end of each animation cycle
I want to use Anime.js to achieve animations consistent with CSS
This is the effect I achieved using CSS：
 <div class="box">
    <span class="box-item" style="--i: 1"></span>
    <span class="box-item" style="--i: 2"></span>
    <span class="box-item" style="--i: 3"></span>
    <span class="box-item" style="--i: 4"></span>
    <span class="box-item" style="--i: 5"></span>
 </div>

<style>
.box {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box-item {
  animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: calc(1s * var(--i));
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #e5f6ff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px 20px;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
</style>

This is the effect I achieved using animejs：
<script>
  const boxItems = document.querySelectorAll(".box-item");

  anime({
    targets: boxItems,
    easing: "linear",
    duration: 3000,
    loop: true,
    keyframes: [
      { width: 0, height: 0, opacity: 1 },
      { width: 300, height: 300, opacity: 0, easing: "linear" },
    ],
    delay: anime.stagger(500),
  });

</script>
 <div class="box">
    <span class="box-item"></span>
    <span class="box-item"></span>
    <span class="box-item"></span>
    <span class="box-item"></span>
    <span class="box-item"></span>
 </div>
<style>
.box {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box-item {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #e5f6ff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px 20px;
}
</style>


I have tried to make it seamless with help of setInterval but its not how you want. But I have found the cause of issue which is delay: anime.stagger(100) this also adds delay for each circle but also adds delay after each loop.

Thank you for sharing your attempts and findings. I've been struggling with this issue for a long time. I once solved this problem using GSAP, but GSAP is too heavy for my needs.
